# S3 Redirection Rules for API Gateway not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I am following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) and create `Lambda` , `API Gateway` and `S3 bucket`

Integration of Lambda and Api gateway is done and also logs.
Issue I face is Api Gaetway is not accessible in S3 bucket.

I enable `Use this bucket to host a website` in properties and add `index.html` for index document.

Redirection Rule is

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
<Condition>
  <KeyPrefixEquals/>
  <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
</Condition>
<Redirect>
  <Protocol>https</Protocol>
  <HostName>xyz.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
  <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/api</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
  <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
</Redirect>
```

When I hit s3 bucket image which not exists there, it should hit this API Gateway and logs in `Cloudwatch` but it's not happen.

If I hit APIGaetway url directly, it logs

Comment: This is probably not the best way to build this integration, but try setting `<HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>` to 403, not 404.

Comment: no impact of that @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: If it isn't working, the what does it actually do?  Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try by enabling  CORS in the API gateway. PFB for option .

1. Go to API gateway 
   2.select your API and When its in Resource tab, Go to Actions drop down and
2. Select the "Enable CORS" and click on "Enable Cors and Replace existing CORs headers"